# как оставить те ключи, каторые являются массивами в generic

Tags: reactjs, typescript

трудно описать, кину код

вот интерфейс хука, мне нужны в innerArrayDataKey доступ к тем ключам каторые являются массивом

```
type TData = any;
interface IUseCheckboxWithDropdownArgs<T extends Array<TData>> {
  isCheckedAll: boolean;
  data: T;
  innerArrayDataKey: keyof T[0];
}
```

приминение

```
const {
  checkedCheckboxes,
  handleArrowIconClick,
  handleChangeCheckedCheckboxValue,
  isShow,
  selectedId,
} = useCheckboxWithDropdown<TConnectionPoints['data']>({
  data,
  isCheckedAll,
  innerArrayDataKey: 'objects', //сейчас тут можно выбрать все ключи из data, а нужны те каторые являются массивом
});
```

если нунжы будут еше какие то участки кода для ответа , дайте знать, спасибо.